# Using count in limit clause

Tags: sql, postgresql

Is there a way to use a select count() in the limit clause of a SQL query?

Original query:

```
SELECT *
FROM flight_delays
LIMIT 10;
```

but something dynamic like this:

```
SELECT
  *
FROM
  flight_delays
LIMIT
  (
    select
      count(foo)
    from
      bar
    group by
      bar.bing
  )
```

Comment: This is quite unclear. Would you please show sample data and expected output ?

Comment: @GMB the expression in the limit clause needs to reduce to an integer (evalute to an integer)

Comment: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.6/queries-limit.html

Comment: Your sql should work, can you post the error that is raised when you try to execute it?

Answer (score 0):

You can do:

```
SELECT fd.*
FROM (SELECT fd.*, ROW_NUMBER() OVER () as seqnum
      FROM flight_delays
     ) fd CROSS JOIN
     (select count(foo) as cnt
      from bar
     ) x
WHERE seqnum <= x.cnt;
```

Comment: Basically I was thinking there was a way to use a count/sum expression in the limit clause and it would reduce to an integer, but according to the Postgres docs only integer and ALL expression work for the limit clause. I don't see how an ALL expression works there though.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a function that will first calculate the value of the `LIMIT` and then execute the query with that `LIMIT`.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION flight_delays_limited()
  RETURNS setof flight_delays
  $$
  DECLARE
    limitSize INTEGER = 0;
  BEGIN
  --custom logic for calculating the limit
  select
      count(foo) into limitSize
    from
      bar
    group by
      bar.bing;
  --end custom logic

  --return result from select with calculated limit
  RETURN QUERY
  SELECT * FROM flight_delays
    LIMIT limitSize;
  end;
$$ language plpgsql;
```

You can call the function like this:

```
SELECT * FROM flight_delays_limited();
```